# Sending HTTP request from Netduino

Tags: c#, netduino

I have Netduino Plus and I need it to send Http requests to my server. I'm not a guru in C#, I've never tried it before, so I copy/paste code from internet and try to make it works. But even after several hours I can't get it work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware;
using SecretLabs.NETMF.Hardware.NetduinoPlus;

namespace NetduinoPlusApplication5
{
  public class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {

        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com?variable=1");
        request.Method = "GET";
        var result = request.GetResponse();
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: It doesn't work. That's the problem :(

Comment: That's a useless description of the problem. If you call a mechanic and tell him/her your car "doesn't work", they'll hang up on you. What is the specific problem? Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a GET request so I think you want to get the response body from the server. In this case you have to use :

Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

instead of simple GetResponse(). In this way, you can read on the stream the response body.

Paolo.